# How do I apply encodeURIComponent() before submit?

Tags: jquery, submit, jeditable, encodeuricomponent

I'm trying to apply `encodeURIComponent()` to the data before submitting it to the server. 
I've tried :

```
submitdata: function (value, settings) {
    return {
        value: encodeURIComponent(value)
    }
},
```

but this doesn't work. It always picks the old value. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. I did

```
var submitdata = function (value, settings) {
    return {
        value: encodeURIComponent(value);
    }
}

var x = submitdata("http://abc.com/?{sss}&as=ee", 1);

alert(x.value);
```

returns

```
"http%3A%2F%2Fabc.com%2F%3F%7Bsss%7D%26as%3Dee"
```